# How to use the JSON Filter Plugin for Logstash

Tags: json, filter, logstash, elastic-stack

I have read this documentation on their website (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) and am still struggling to understand how to use this plugin. The goal I had was to take a JSON file and cut out everything except for a few particular fields that are spread out around a JSON log. Does the Add_field filter make it so only the fields added are passed on? If so how would I specify what to pass on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON filter is for expanding json in a field. For reading a JSON file into logstash you probably want to use the [`json` codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json.html) with a [`file` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html), somewhat like this:

```
file {
    path => "/path/to/file"
    codec => "json"
}
```

That will read a json file into logstash as one event or

> If the data being sent is a JSON array at its root multiple events will be created (one per element).

Then you could use a [`mutate` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html) to remove the fields you don't want.

```
mutate {
  remove_field => [ "uneeded-field", "my_extraneous_field" ]
}
```

You could also look into using the community [`prune` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-prune.html), which can remove everything except a whitelist.